# How to change return of core function from Shopware's listener

Tags: php, listener, shopware

Question is about Shopware, e-commerce platform.
I have a requirement to change the way urls, to products in shop, are saved.
Customer wants short url so just first category is saved. No category path.

Not category1/category2/category3/productname

but this one category1/productname.

Tried something from backend Basic Settings-> Frontend -> SEO route settings -> SEO URL's Item template. But could not make it work.

So I tried with listener. Event:

```
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            'sRewriteTable::sSmartyCategoryPath::before' => 'onTableRewrite'
        ];
    }
```

And associated function:

```
public function onTableRewrite(\Enlight_Hook_HookArgs $args)
    {
        /** @var \Shopware_Controllers_Backend_Article $subject */
        $subject = $args->getSubject();
        $paramArgs = $args->getArgs();
        //$args->setReturn('asdfasdf');
        //$paramArgs = $args->set('categoryID', 1);

        if(!empty($paramArgs[0]['articleID'])){
            return 'ThisisKeva';
        } 

        return true;
    }
```

I tried to return something just to see if it works but it never works. Like my listener has no effect on how core function works. But it stops with die();

How to change what core function returns from the listener? 
Is it possible? Did I misunderstand something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a plugin for this. You can use this as product seo template:

```
{assign var='tree' value='/'|explode:{sCategoryPath articleID=$sArticle.id}}{$tree.0}/{$sArticle.name}
```

Explanation:

1. Add the category tree to a variable and split it to an array
2. Use the first entry of the array as key

Comment: Thanks mate! I owe you a beer